# firebase database child reference issue

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am trying to create a meeting firebase reference inside my parent `users`

I am implementing this line:

```
var meetingRef= firebase.database().ref('users/' + $rootScope.currentUser.$id + '/meetings');
```

Under my `users`, I have registered user `Id's` as hashes, which I make use of in the above code. As the current user gets authenticated, he gets to create some meetings from the UI. I want these meetings to go into his particular hash in the firebase database.

But every time I create a meeting, some `undefined` child reference of `users` gets created under which I see the meetings of authenticated users.

This is my complete code-

```
myApp.controller("MeetingsController",
    ['$scope','$rootScope','$firebaseArray',
    function($scope,$rootScope,$firebaseArray){

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
     var auth = firebase.auth();

        auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            var meetingRef= firebase.database().ref('users/' + $rootScope.currentUser.$id + '/meetings');
            var meetingsInfo=$firebaseArray(data);

            $scope.addmeeting=function(){
                meetingsInfo.$add({
                    name:$scope.meetingname,
                    date:firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                }).then(function(){
                    $scope.meetingname=' ';
                })
            };
          }
        });

}]);
```

If you are wondering as to where that `$rootScope.users.$id` value is coming. It comes from a service that I created and the `$id` is the value that the current authenticated user's hash is.

I want the meetings to go inside authenticated users hash. I think I am creating wrong  reference path. How can I achieve this one?

Images attached:

Current:

[image]

Required:

[image]

Comment: Can you post something showing the structure you are trying to create, along with the structure you are actually creating? So we can better visualize your intentions and results.

Comment: Made appraopriate changes to the post. Please have a look. @Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this one. 
I changed the meetingRef to:

`var meetingRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/meetings');`

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Aakash,

Your code to create the `meetings` folder and the drawing you added to the post do not go together. Currently, you are using this:

```
var data = firebase.database().ref('users/' + $rootScope.currentUser.$id + '/meetings');
```

But if you really want `meetings` to be a direct child of `users` the way you have drawn then you will need to get rid of the user id piece of the reference like this:

```
var data = firebase.database().ref('users/meetings');
```

This is based off what you added to your post, however, something tells me that you didn't mean to draw `meetings` in there as a direct child to users. If that's what you really wanted, then that would be your answer.

This next piece is a guess, but is the following structure what you are trying to create?

[image]

Because if it is, you need something different which I can also help with, just let me know.

**Update:**

Ok, based on your comment, I see that you are going for the data structure in my picture.

It looks like your code is ok, however, at the exact moment that the `data` variable is being set, your `$rootScope.currentUser.$id` is `undefined`. This is possibly due to the asynchronous nature of javascript.  This means that sometimes your `user` variable is true, however, your `$rootScope.currentUser.$id` is still not quite caught up and is `undefined`.

I would run a check on the variable before continuing, just to make sure everything is in order:

```
if($rootScope.currentUser.$id != undefined){
    var data = firebase.database().ref('users/' + $rootScope.currentUser.$id + '/meetings');
}else{
    return;
}
```

This will stop you from ever getting a new `undefined` object in your database.

Comment: Exactly right. The image that you added is exactly the thing that I am looking for. @ryan

Comment: Are those other 'users' created with a 'meetings' inside of them? So what I mean is, are you getting all the correct behavior, but then you get that extra 'undefined' at the end that you don't want? If so, take a look at my update to my answer and it should solve your problem. If, however, those other 'users' are not created properly, let me know.